# Find minimal polynomial over different fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a_1^2=2$,  $a_2^2=3$. Find minimal polynomial of $a_1+a_2$ over $\mathbb {Q}$, $\mathbb {F}_5$, and $\mathbb {F}_7$.

---

This problem is for Galois theory, but I do not know how to use it to solve at all.
I only find that for $\mathbb {Q}$, maybe I can do it directly. And for example maybe $(x^2-5)^2-24$ is the minimal polynomial of $2^{1/2}+3^{1/2}$. But I think it is not the right way of working out this problem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "maybe"? Why do you think that? Waht calculations did you do?

Comment: I think the first step is to show that $x^2 - 2$ and $x^2 - 3$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{F}_5$ and $\mathbb{F}_7$ by Eisenstein and brute force checking respectively.

Comment: @DonAntonio I just noticed that the minimal polynomial of it should not be of degree 1 or 2, then you can square it and make the square root of 6 out by the polynomial I mentioned, of degree 4, so I think it should be the minimal polynomial. Am I right?

Comment: @Ivan Yes, you are...but  a more formal proof is going to be needed, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

$$x:=\sqrt2+\sqrt3\implies x^2=5+2\sqrt6\implies (x^2-5)^2-24=0\iff x^4-10x^2+1=0$$

Prove the last polynomial appearing in that equation is irreducible over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ .

In $\;\Bbb F_7\;$ , we have that

$$3^2=2\implies \sqrt2\in\Bbb F_7\;,\;\;\text{but}\;\;\sqrt3\notin\Bbb F_7$$

so we only need

$$x-\sqrt2=\sqrt3\implies x^2-2\sqrt2x+2=3\implies x^2-6x+6=0$$

and it is automatic the last polynomial is irreducible (why?)

For $\;\Bbb F_5\;$ do something similar as the above

Comment: You are right. And the same process for different + - sign of x is needed another 3 times.

Comment: But I think that this answer is just using the basic property of field and it depends on the specific element. Is there a generally valid method for calculating the minimal polynomial of an element over a field, at least for finite field, using Galois theory?

Comment: @Ivan No that I know, and I really don't think so. Things would be extremely easy if there were such a general method. This will usually depend on specific elements and specific field